# Append Random Text without Repetition for File (C)

Tags: c, file, random

I have 5 list of name

`char *name[] = {"a","b","c","d","e"};`

and I have 3 files

```
char path1[PATH_MAX+1]
snprintf(path1, PATH_MAX+1, "%sfile1.txt",dirname);
FILES *filename1 = fopen(path1, "w")
.
.
.
char path3[PATH_MAX+1]
snprintf(path3, PATH_MAX+1, "%sfile3.txt",dirname);
FILES *filename3 = fopen(path3, "w")
```

What I want is to randomly append **a,b,c,d,e** (one of them per file) into three of those files without repetition.

What I have right now is *(example from one of them)*

```
srand(time(NULL));
int one = rand()%5;
char path1[PATH_MAX+1];
snprintf(path1, PATH_MAX+1, "%sfile1.txt",dirname);
FILES *filename1 = fopen(path1, "w");
fputs(name[one],filename1);
fclose(filename1);
```

However, sometimes it is still possible where my **file1.txt** and **file3.txt** both contain **b** *(same alphabet from name)*

**Questions**

Did I miss something to make sure that all the random result always unique?

Is it also efficient tho to have 6 lines of code to create one file and append a random name inside it? I'm just wondering if I have to create like 20 files, I will write 120 lines that basically almost the same, just different in number (filename**1** to filename**3**)

Thank you.

Comment: 1. why `rand() % 10` while you only have 5 'names'? 2. I see absolutely nothing in your code to ensure preventing duplicates. 3. You don't append, you overwrite the contents of your files.

Comment: @Jongware 1) I edit it into 5 already. 2) I'm guessing srand(time(NULL)) doesn't help, yes? Sorry, I'm kinda new with C programming.

Comment: srand() is initializing the random generator and time(NULL) returns the current system time. This makes sense to ensure that the random generator does not generate always the same sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a unique sequence of characters, you can draw them from a diminishing pool. For example, after you have picked the `a`, it is removed from the pool. Of course, the pool must be at least as big as the number of files you want to print.

A simple way to implement this sort of picking is to pick a char from the pool, move the last character from the pool to the place of the picked character and decrease the pool size by one.

If you see a lot of repetition of code, especially if the only difference is a variable name along the lines of `filename1`, `filename2`, `filename3` and so on should ring a bell that you should use an array: `FILE *file[NFILE]`. Be aware, though, that you can only have a certain number of files open at a time.

In your case, you want to write a single character to a file. There's no need to have multiple file s open simultaneously: Open a file, pick a char, write it to the file, close e file. Then  process the next file.

The program below does what you want, I think.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NFILES 10

int main()
{
    char pool[] = "abcdefghij";     // Available chars as array
    int npool = sizeof(pool) - 1;   // Pool size minus terminating '\0'
    int i;

    if (npool < NFILES) {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Not enough letters in pool for %d files.\n", NFILES);
        exit(1);
    }

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < NFILES; i++) {
        int ipick = rand() % npool;    // position of pick
        char pick = pool[ipick];       // picked char

        char fname[20];
        FILE *f;

        pool[ipick] = pool[--npool];   // remove pick from pool

        snprintf(fname, sizeof(fname), "file-%03d.txt", i);

        f = fopen(fname, "w");
        if (f == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", fname);
            exit(1);
        }

        fprintf(f, "%c\n", pick);
        fclose(f);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This makes more sense using for loop compare to changing all the var. Also, i didnt think that I can move the position to the end. I stop thinking to remove it since I know array element cant be deleted. Thank you

Comment: Well, the idea is to take away the last element and put it where the picked item was. The size of the array `sizeof(pool)` is fixed, but the effective size `npool` can shrink. (If you swap the picked element with the last element, you have shuffled the original array.)

Comment: You can. The data in the pool array can be of any type. Of course you have `const char *pick` then and you must print the string with the `%s` format. And you must calculate `npool` accordingly.

Comment: I've adjusted the code with mine, but why there is still repetition and also sometimes the file contain like garbage random like `"connect:host@dfjlaskdfjasdf"` inside the file?

Comment: That's hard to answer without seeing the code. Now is a good time to learn about debugging your code. Is `npool` correct? Is `ipick` a reasonable choice? The code above works, but needs adjustments when your array stores elements of another data type. Also, be sure to compile with warnings on.