# Create & Append Files into Directory

Tags: c, random, directory

I kinda have similar questions like this guy (coava) posted.

([Append Random Text without Repetition for File (C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361900/append-random-text-without-repetition-for-file-c/33362553?noredirect=1#comment54549990_33362553))

The summary: Basically I'm trying to create files, append random words into it and store the files into a directory

I've tried the solution given but it doesn't work for me, maybe because in my case I'm storing those file in the directory as well.

So my code (EDIT: THIS IS piece of my code) looks like this:

```
char *room[4];
room[0] = "okay";
room[1] = "sure";
room[2] = "fine";
room[3] = "noo";

int pid = getpid();
char dirname[30]
sprintf(dirname,"rooms.%d",(int)getpid());
mkdir(dirname,0777);

int bufSize=128;
char *current = malloc(bufSize);
int nroom = sizeof(room) - 1;
int count;

for (count=0;count<3;count++) {
 int ipick = rand()%nroom;
 int *pick = room[ipick];
 room[nroom] = room [--nroom];
 snprintf(currentFile,bufSize,"file-%d.txt",count);
 FILE *f = fopen(currentFile,"w")
 fprintf(f, "YOUR ROOM: %s\n",pick);
 fclose(f);
}
```

Then I get a seg.fault, I tried to modify

```
snprintf(currentFile,bufSize,"file-%d.txt",count);
```

into

```
snprintf(currentFile,bufSize,"file-%d.txt",dirname,count);
```

It didn't give seg.fault, but it just print outside the directory with the addition of inside of each file sometimes I got random value like

"connection host: @blablabla" or some junk symbol.

Is there something wrong in my **for** loop? Or is it somewhere else?

Comment: *So my code looks pretty much like this* is meaningless. Post your **actual code** if you want help figuring out why it doesn't work. Posting something *like it* means you could introduce new errors (or leave out real ones) while you're making up the code. Copy/paste the *relevant portions* of your **actual code** into the question.

Comment: @KenWhite That's my real code....

Comment: 'int nroom = sizeof(room) - 1;' - that doesn't look good:(

Comment: @MartinJames May I know why?

Comment: You presumably need: `snprintf(currentFile, bufSize, "%s/file-%d.txt", dirname, count);` — you forgot to put in a conversion specification to process the directory name.  You also need to add all the compiler warnings (`gcc -Wall` at bare minimum; `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes` is close to what I use (I use some other more esoteric flags too).

Comment: It's the size of four pointers, In bytes, less 1.  So, on common systems,  it's gonna be 15 or 31.

Comment: well your 'real' code isn't even a complete function, must less compilable.

Comment: when calling system functions, like mkdir() and malloc(), fopen() the returned value needs to be checked to assure the operation was successful

Comment: Run it under your debugger and, well, step through the lines and inspect stuff at each stage to see if it's what you expect.

Comment: @MartinJames Okay so I decided just to hardcoded instead by saying, `int nroom = sizeof(room) - 1;` into `int nroom=3` and it works. However, why it is still created outside the directory and I still see repetition?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler may I know what is *"conversion specification to process the directory name"* means?

Comment: this line: `int nroom = sizeof(room) - 1;`  will (depending on the system architecture set 'nroom' to 15 or 31  because room[] is 4 pointers so the sizeof will return 4 * sizeof char * ).  to get the desired value use: `int nroom = sizeof(room)/sizeof(char*) - 1;`

Comment: The `%s` is the conversion specification for putting a string into the output. 'Conversion specification' is the formal name for the [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) family format notations starting with a `%` and ending with a type letter.  You added `dirname` to the argument list for your `snprintf()` call, but you didn't add the `%s` to process it, so the `%d` was taking the address value of `dirname` and using that to format the number — not what you wanted.

Comment: Note:  a 'pid' is a 'pid_t', not necessarily a 'int'   and after obtaining the pid of the current process into the 'pid' variable, what call getpid() again, just a couple lines later.  (the pid will not have changed)

Comment: the posted code has several `magic` numbers.  `magic` numbers make code difficult to understand and are a real headache when debugging/performing maintenance.  Suggest use either #define or enum to give the numbers meaningful names and using those names throughout the code.  examples of the `magic` numbers are : 4, 30, 128

Comment: @user3629249 yeah I got the int nroom fixed already, because I decided to hardcoded instead. Also, those magic numbers are just a fixed number that I decided from the beginning. It is kinda stupid sorry.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so I tried to `snprintf(currentFile,bufSize,"%s file-%d.txt",dirname,count);` but it just printing `<dirname>.file-<number>` Do I need to remove something?

Comment: I had a `/` in the format that you don't have in yours.  It prefixes the directory name and a slash before the file name so you get the file created in the directory.  While you don't include the slash, the files will be created in the current directory.  You don't want any space in the format string either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *room[4] = { "okay", "sure", "fine", "noo" };
    int pid = getpid();
    char dirname[30];
    sprintf(dirname, "rooms.%d", pid);
    if (mkdir(dirname, 0777) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Oops: did not create directory %s\n", dirname);
        exit(1);
    }

    int bufSize = 128;
    char *current = malloc(bufSize);
    int nroom = 4; // sizeof(room) - 1;

    for (int count = 0; count < 3; count++)
    {
        int ipick = rand() % nroom;
        char *pick = room[ipick];
        room[ipick] = room[--nroom];
        snprintf(current, bufSize, "%s/file-%d.txt", dirname, count);
        FILE *f = fopen(current, "w");
        if (f != 0)
        {
            fprintf(f, "YOUR ROOM: %s\n", pick);
            fclose(f);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There are lots of little corrections.  One bigger one is the code that shuffles the list of words as they're used.  Another is the value set for `nroom`.  I simplified life to a constant 4; you could use `sizeof(room) / sizeof(room[0])` instead and it will grow as the array grows.  I used an array initializer rather than assignments — and could have omitted the `4` from the array size (it would automatically be sized for the number of values in the initializer).

It will produce the same result (same set of files with the same content) each time it is run.  Add `#include <time.h>` to the headers and `srand(time(0));` before the loop to get different results on different runs.  It's a very simplistic way of seeding the random number generator.  `getpid()` instead of `time(0)` also has some merits.

Comment: Your advice about adding `%s/` works directly in my code, however since you already wrote the whole code anyway, I would say thank you for the help. Also, I think it is to declare the constant directly, since when I tried that, no more seg. fault appear.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, sorry for asking you a question again. However, it may seems to work but why after several time I run it, sometimes there are still 2 or 3 files that has the same appended name? `room2.txt and room3.txt contain "okay"`

Comment: I've updated my copy of the program (not the copy in the answer) with `srand(pid);` before the loop, and it prints out the directory name.  Over 100 runs, I didn't get any repeats.  Did you make all the changes in the loop that I made?  Your original code was incorrect.

Comment: Ah ya my bad, I still kept the `room[nroom] = room[--nroom];` instead of the `room[ipick] = room[--nroom];` from you. Thanks for the clarification.